# How to set specific row to one and rest all others to zero?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, logic

How to set a specific row to one and all other entries of a matrix to zero?

For example let us consider the matrix below

```
Matrix M = 0 0 0 
           1 0 5
           2 0 4
           5 6 8
           0 3 10
```

I want to set for example **row number 4** to ones like in the *Result* and the rest to zero.

```
Result = 0 0 0
         0 0 0 
         0 0 0 
         1 1 1
         0 0 0
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you realize that you don't really need the original matrix for this? The only relevant input is the index of the row and the size of the matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new and it takes a while for me to figure things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the simplicity of the task, I would rather recommend creating a new matrix. Just use the size of the original matrix. Assume you have matrix `A`.

```
B = zeros(size(A));
```

This will create a matrix `B` of all 0s of the same size as `A`. Then, if you need to change the value of one of the rows (e.g. row 4 in your example)

```
B(4,:)=1;
```

Will assign 1s to all the values in that row. I would recommend reading [this page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) on matrix indexing in matlab before asking any further questions ;)

Comment: no worries, doing a few tutorials and reading the documentation is usually a good start. For example see [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html)